# how to remove entirely the python directory?

Tags: python

Please help me to resolve this issue about the removing of the python directory.  There is the stack trace of my bug when I  try to remove the python directory  using the following command `apt-get autoremove python`

```
ImportError: No module named debpython
dpkg: error processing python-pkg-resources (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing python-psutil ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/update-python-modules", line 16, in <module>

Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. A lot of important stuff relies on Python, possibly including the tool you're trying to use to uninstall Python.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

```
 sudo apt-get purge *your-program-name*
```

this will totally (well... almost) delete your program and its library(ies)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your response. I try this command line but it generate the same error.There is another way to resolve this problem? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I find the solution and it's works for me when I use the following command:

$ pip uninstall python